# Where can I find a comparison between TFS and VSTS Reporting abilities?

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, azure-devops

I've read that TFS supports SSRS and VSTS supports Power BI but I have not found any meaningful comparison on the actual reports or their usefulness. Nor about which might have different or better dashboards. Anyone know of any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search shows up with this link for Dashboards and reports for VSTS and TFS. Shows Power BI, SSRS reports, and indicates which ones are exclusive to the platforms.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/overview

As for usefulness, that all depends on your organization and is a bit subjective because of how each org uses reports.